# Inheritance causes class to act like it is Shared

Tags: vb.net, winforms, inheritance

When using inheritance on Winforms, it causes the class to appear Shared. 
Why only the second line in the Main method displays a syntax warning? TestForm102.Widgets.Count should highlight the same issue.

Note: I added the MustInherit to TestForm101 to highlight the issue (...what it should display). If I remove it, the form simply acts like it is shared too.

[image]

Comment: Please post the code rather than a screenshot.

Comment: You need an instance of `TestForm102` (nice name!) first, despite inheritance.

Comment: I think you missed my point... this is just a code sample to prove that an inherited form can wrongly be accessed without creating an instance of said form. I'm after any possible solution to stop any of our developers wrongly using the class rather than an instance of the class.

Comment: ..note that the first line 'TestForm102.Widgets.Count' does not cause a runtime error either, it actually generates a new instance of the form when accessed - something I'd be keen to avoid...though this has caused us an issue in production (where we have classes from different binaries interacting).

Comment: `I'm after any possible solution to stop our developers wrongly using the class rather than an instance of the class.` the actual post doesnt seem to reflect what you are really after.  More than one person has "missed the point". inheritance  has nothing to do with it - VB simply allows default instancing

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix... that explains it.. I'd never heard of Default Instancing (which I've now found out was 're-introduced' in VS2005 from VB6) and believed it was the inheritance that must have been causing it.. my background is not VB6 but early .Net. Anyhow, can it be turned off as we always deal with instances we create - as in OOP, and do not want these objects floating around.

Comment: Unfortunately it cannot be turned off.  It is bad in many cases but it also makes VB accessible to "tinkerers" who have no knowledge of OOP and classes etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line works because `TestForm102` is an instance of `TestForm102` rather than a type as one would expect. It's auto-generated by VS and you'll find it in [My.Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87y2hdsf.aspx). You're last line fails because VS cannot auto-generate an instance of a `MustInherit` form and/or a form without a public parameterless constructor. At this point `TestForm101` is a type, and as observed, you cannot reference a non-shared member without an object reference.

```vb
Dim y As Integer = My.Forms.TestForm102.Widgets.Count '<-Ok
Dim x As Integer = My.Forms.TestForm101.Widgets.count '<-Error
```

> ***Error:*** 'TestForm101' is not a member of ...MyForms

Comment: And THIS is why default form instances were a BAD idea.

Comment: I've never heard of 'Default Instancing' until now... so lame. Why they decided to re-introduce a 'classic' VB idea to VS2005 is beyond me. My background is not VB pre .Net, rather IBM RPG/400.